# Поворот объекта относительно заданной точки

Tags: android, opengl, разработка-игр, opengles

У меня есть прямоугольник 100 на 50, который я хочу повернуть относительно точки, к примеру, (20, 10), но у меня никак не выходит. Лучшее, чего я смог добиться - поворот по левому верхнему углу:

```java
Matrix.multiplyMM(rotationMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(rotationMatrix, 0, myPosX, myPosY, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1.0f);
```

Как можно вращать объект относительно некоторой точки?

Comment: Матрица очень сложный инструмент в плане ресурсов, она перерисовывает фигуру, точка за точкой, и это огромная нагрузка на процессы, чтоб этого не происходило и существуют анимации, которые работают уже не с рисовалками, а объектами(в большинстве), что значительно ускоряет процесс. В вашем случае используйте rotate анимацию, где вы можете также указать относительную точку вращения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы повернуть объект относительно заданной точки необходимо текущую матрицу трансформации умножить на матрицу смещения точки вращение в центр координат. Назовём эту матрицу offsetMatrix. Если центр вашего прямоугольника находится в центре координат, то offsetMatrix должна смещать на вектор (20 - 100 / 2, 10 - 50 / 2). Правда не знаю инвертирован ли у вас Y, возможно Y должен быть со знаком "-". Затем умножаем на матрицу вращения (rotateMatrix), а потом умножаем на обратную матрицу смещения (offsetMatrix^-1), что бы вернуть объект в первоначальную позицию. Сходя из всего выше сказанного, получаем вот такую формулу:

```
resultMatrix =  (offsetMatrix^-1) * rotateMatrix * offsetMatrix * originalMatrix;
```

originalMatrix - это ваша первоначальная матрица.

Данная картинка демонстрируют это вычисление

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на статью с изображением.](http://www.tvd-home.ru/prog/13_7)

Comment: а у вас примерчика готового нету случайно? прошу прощения за наглость)) уже третий день мучаюсь). оно либо вокруг начала координат вращается, либо вокруг левого верхнего угла прямоугольника.

Comment: Я так смотрю вы разрабатываете под Android и на Java, наверное. Я просто не знаком с этим SDK. Пришлите ссылку на документацию по классу Matrix, тогда могу примерно написать как оно должно выглядить

Comment: да, под андроид на Java, opengl es 2.0. Спасибо, вот документация на английском: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html

Comment: Я бы делал примерно так: Matrix.translateM(rotationMatrix, 0, offsetX, offsetY, 0); Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, angle, 0, 0, 1.0f); Matrix.translateM(rotationMatrix, 0, -offsetX, -offsetY, 0); Где offsetX, offsetY - это смещения точки вращения в начало координат.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь) до того как спросить, я был близок к решению, у меня была ошибка в формуле смещения